# What is ths timeout for firestore get , set method and How to increase get and set method timeout in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

What is the timeout for firestore get and set methods and how to increase the timeout for these in Android?

```
db.document(documents path).get()   // what is the timeout for get() method
db.document(documents path).set(data, SetOptions.merge());  // what is the timeout for set() method
```

How to increase this timeout in slow internet connection ?

Answer (score 1):

`get()` and `set()` don't have a timeout.  The SDK will keep trying until it gets a response, or there is an error that says the query will *never* succeed (such as when a security rule rejects the request).

Comment: addSnapshotListener also not getting called in slow internet connection , there is any timeout or network issue with addSnapshotListener.

Comment: No, there are never any timeouts. The SDK will keep trying until the app comes online.